# What is the encryption function in Encfs?

Tags: encryption, filesystems, fuse

I'm a newbie at Encfs. After I read a paper about Encfs, I figured out there is a Encryption layer in Encfs. So I tried to find exact encryption function. but I couldn't find that because there are many functions. Does anyone have any idea or advice?

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Cipher" in Encfs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS#Cipher

And at the moment is Blowfish and AES.